# How do I resolve 'No projects supported by NuGet in the solution' error in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studios 2022 "No projects supported by NuGet in the solution"

I have two projects in my solution, both have previously been using 2 packages installed from NuGet and continue to be updated by NuGet. Recently I tried to install another package that seemed to have never installed properly or may have been incompatabile because it the reference wasn't resolving when trying to use it. I then removed that package and searched for a compatible verison or altnertive. However, when the package manager wouldn't load/display when selecting it from a project within the solution. Selecting "Manage NuGet Packages for solution..." results in the following error: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne0FV.png)

I then noticed that there was no default project in the Package Manager Console and none of my projects showed up: [Default Project Drop Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmGIb.png)

I've also tried repairing Visual Studio 2022 but that didn't seem to do anything either.

**UPDATE:** Solution was to create a new project, select "Manage NuGet Packages" and then go back to the previous solution.

Comment: have you tried to delete the .vs hidden folder that is inside the solution folder?, maybe something wento wrong

Comment: See my anwer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update:**

The solution of this issue is to create a new project, select "Manage Nuget Packages" and then go back to the previous solution.

In this situation, the root issue doesn't cause by the solution configuration but come from something went wrong in VS.

**Original Answer:**

For the issue you mentioned, there have already an issue in Github, and here is the solution to it:

[Operated failed. No projects supported by NuGet in the solution throws for a upgraded NetCore project](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7216#issuecomment-417832720)

**Close and reopen the Visual Studio, and then click Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for solution:**

[image]

By the way, **you can also try the method that DonMiguelSanchez provided**, because .vs folder under the root directory of solution have information of the loaded solution, if you delete/remove this folder, Visual Studio will regenerate this file when you restart the Visual Studio and open the solution.

Comment: I've already tried that. It just provides with me the same error listed in my question. Deleting the .vs directory didn't change anything either.

Comment: @Prasinos333 What about creating a new solution, will the issue still exists? Just want to confirm whether it is a solution issue or VS issue. :)

Comment: I was delaying trying to make a new project cause I didn't want to move everything over. Turns out I didn't need to, I've updated the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solution is not working, creating a new project, openning it and then openning "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." and then reopenning old project didn't change anything. I also tried to delete .vs folder which still didn't change anything. When I click the "Manage...." I still get "No projects supported by NuGet in the solution"